# Show html image over screen. not in a new window

Tags: html, image, frame, target

Is it possible to make an image open on click (like target="_blank") but not in a new window - i want to open in over current page. Iframe is something that works fine for me but i want that frame to be hidden until image is clicked. Is there some html component that can work for me?

Comment: Do you want to navigate the user to just the image?  Do you want to display the image in a kind of "modal pop-up" on the current page?  Something else?  What have you tried?

Comment: yes., something like that, there are few small images on my page and when user click on one of them i want that picture to be shown over my page but in full size, without opening new tab and forcing user to close tab to return to page... small close button on a image itself will be enough. I am trying to do that in a wordpress so i dont want to mess with jquery only for this...

Comment: There are various plugins which have functionality like this, or you can write your own.  A common term used to describe the functionality is a "light box", or more generically a "modal div".  With the terminology you can find examples and tutorials to help get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you're trying to do but if I get it right I assume you can avoid using `target="_blank"`. By default href open your content on the same page on which you clicked. (Using HTML attribute, this would be the same of using `target="_self"` if you want to show it on the same frame where it was clicked.

Comment: no, target="_self" makes it even worse ...

Comment: Ok so please post some code or a snippet of what you want to achieve